# TinyMce formatting

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

when adding a content to tinymce the formatting works fine the image,text are saved in database as it should be but when I fetch the content from the database and put it into tinyMce all the html are removed and images are not displayed and the formatting of the content is also lost

But when the content is put outside the tinymce it Displays perfectly !

Now how can i achieve the same result inside tinyMce that is images and formating of contents are displayed as saved in database  !!

Here is the image to show whats the issue is

[image]

Any Kind of Help is Appreciated !!

Comment: Can you share your code that loads the HTML from your database back into TinyMCE?

Comment: <div class="panel-body"><textarea name="page_content" class="form-control" id="page_content" rows="10" cols="30">
                               {!!$page->page_content!!} 
                        </textarea>
                            </div>

Comment: If you are placing content directly into the `textarea` you need to encode the HTML (e.g. `<` becomes `&lt;`).

Comment: No still its not working .... i am putting the content directly into textarea which is a text editor TInyMce so the tags are stripped

Answer (score 0):

You can using html_entity_decode()
Watch more in [Html Entity Decode](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_html_entity_decode.asp)

Comment: Try this: {!!html_entity_decode($page->page_content)!!}